# See services in DDMS

Tags: android, service, ddms

Is there a solution to see in DDMS which services are currently running ?

I'm looking something similar to the thread view to check the binding/unbinding on the  service of my application.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a solution to see in DDMS which services are currently running ?

No, sorry. However, `adb shell dumpsys activity services` should give you what you need, albeit in a not-exactly-user-friendly output format.